# React Timeout on render

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react . I want to delay the loading of a content. When the page loads i want to show a content loader like in Facebook. Content is loading so fast that it doesn't wait to show content loader.

```
    renderPage() {
        const {content} = this.props;

            if (!content) {  
              return <Contentloader>;
            }
            else{
                return <Main content={ content } />;
            }            
     }


   render() {
        return (
            <main>
                 { this.renderPage() }
            </main>
        );
    }
```

So how can i delay the loading for sometime in else condition so that i can display contentLoader.

Comment: it is a bad way to show loader if content is already fetched from api , however ans to your que you can use setTimeOut function of javascript to load your content after sometime .

Comment: I understand its wrong but loading section is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this hope this will help

```
state = {
    load: false
}

componentDidMount(){
    if (window.localStorage.getItem('first'))
        return;
    window.localStorage.setItem('first', true);
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
            load: true
        })
    }, 2000)
}



render(){
    return (
        <div>
            {!this.state.load && "your loader"}
            {this.state.load && "your content"}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: @Rspp if this does ans your que than please do it as marked and upvote so, can close this que .

Comment: @ Vyas . I tried this but whenever i come back it continues with loader and then content. Is ther anyway i can do it only first time ??

Comment: @Rspp you can track if page is load first time with help of localstorage if you want i can integrate localstorage with above code .

Comment: Yes please. How can i use localstorage for a this.

Comment: And one more doubt. I have header component in the same page. So how can i make the header component wait until the content is loaded.?

Comment: @Rspp please check edited answer if you found usefull than please upvote this ans. Thank You !!

Comment: same as loader in render function .

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Here header in common component and its loaded by default. So i cant able to find how to do it.

Comment: so, if you still want to hide it ?

Comment: Yes i need to hide it

Comment: only for this page or for all pages ?

Comment: Yes . Only for this page and only first time

Comment: you'r using react-router-dom for routing ? and @Rspp do me a favour if you can not upvote than please upvote all comments in this section .

Comment: Actually i want to add a splash screen for that purpose i want to hide the header.

Comment: in your header component check with `this.props.location.pathname === "/path"` <- this component path name. if condition is true than hide it like above logic .

Comment: In header i need to write the whole logic ??

Comment: yup!! but only for above path logic .

Comment: But header component doesnt have that component. Header is different and This is Mainpage component.Its actually homepag so path is this.props.location.pathname === "/"  How i can link them ?

Comment: please can you put another que with some header & this page code  so i can understand   better & share link with me .

Answer (score 0):

You can add :

```
this.state = {
 loading: true
}
```

to your constructor.

add your timeout function in the render finish the function by:

```
this.setState({loading: false})
```

and for your content:

```
let content = <Loader />;
if(this.state.loading === false){
content = ("Your Content"):
}
```

Comment: i tried adding timeout in compuntDidMount , but its not triggering